# How to add pagination on AJAX filtered data in WordPress?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, pagination

I created one custom post type "Latest Event" and created 3 custom taxonomy "Event_Type", "Event_Location", and "Event_Topic". I have filtered data based on custom taxonomy using AJAX in WordPress. The results are as expected. I also add pagination in main template file. But I am stuck in how to add pagination in filtered data results.

Here is my main template file.

```
<?php
/** Template Name: Events */
get_header();
?>
<?php
      
      $types = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'event_type',
            'hide_empty' => false,
      ));
      $locations = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'event_location',
            'hide_empty' => false,
      ));
      $topics = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'event_topic',
            'hide_empty' => false,
      ));

      $current = get_query_var('paged');
      $options = array(
            'post_type' => 'latest_event',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'paged' => $current
      );
      
      $query = new WP_Query($options);
      
      if ($query->have_posts()) {
?>
      
<div class="latest-events">
      <div class="container">
            <div class="event-filter-form">
                  <h2 class="form-title">Events</h2>
                  <form id="filter-form" name="filter-form" method="GET">
                        <input type="text" name="event_name" id="event_name" placeholder="Search your event here...">
                        <select name="event-type" id="event-type" class="event-type">
                              <option value="" selected>Event Type</option>
                                    <?php
                                          foreach ($types as $type) {
                                    ?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $type->slug; ?>"><?php echo $type->name; ?></option>
                                    <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                        <select name="event-location" id="event-location" class="event-location">
                              <option value="" selected>Event Location</option>
                                    <?php
                                          foreach ($locations as $location) {
                                    ?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $location->slug; ?>"><?php 
                              
                              echo $location->name; ?></option>
                                    <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                        <select name="event-topic" id="event-topic" class="event-topic">
                              <option value="" selected>Event Topic</option>
                                    <?php
                                          foreach ($topics as $topic) {
                                    ?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $topic->slug; ?>"><?php 
                              
                              echo $topic->name; ?></option>
                                    <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                        
                        <input type="submit" value="Apply Filter" name="submit" class="form-submit" >
                  </form>
            </div>
            <div class="event-info">
                  <?php
                        while($query->have_posts()) {
                              $query->the_post();
                  ?>
                  <div class="event-info-card">
                  <h2 class="event-title"><?php the_field('event_name'); ?></h2>
                  <p class="event-organizer">Event by: <?php the_field('event_organizer_name'); ?></p>
                  <p class="event-date">Event date: <?php the_field('event_date'); ?></p>
                  <?php
                        $event_image = get_field('event_image'); 
                        if ($event_image) :
                        $url = $event_image['url'];
                        $alt = $event_image['alt'];
                        $width = $event_image['width'];
                        $height = $event_image['height'];
                  ?> 
                  <img class="event-img" 
                        src="<?php echo esc_url($url); ?>" 
                        alt="<?php echo esc_attr($alt); ?>"
                        width="<?php echo esc_attr($width); ?>"
                        height="<?php echo esc_attr($height); ?>"
                  >
                  <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                  <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="pagination">
                  <?php 
                        echo paginate_links(array(
                              'total' => $query->max_num_pages
                        ));
                  ?>
            </div>
            <?php } 
            wp_reset_postdata();
            
            ?>
             
      </div>
</div>
<?php
      get_footer();
?>
```

Here is my AJAX callback file.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_event_filters', 'event_filters');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_event_filters', 'event_filters');
<?php
      if (! function_exists('event_filters')) {
            function event_filters() {
                  $name = $_GET['event_name'];
                  $tax_query = array();
                  if (! empty($_GET['event_type'])) {
                        $type = sanitize_text_field($_GET['event_type']);
                        
                        $tax_query[] = array(
                              'taxonomy' => 'event_type',
                              'field' => 'slug',
                              'terms' => $type
                        );
                  }
                  if (! empty($_GET['event_location'])) {
                        $location = sanitize_text_field($_GET['event_location']);
                        
                        $tax_query[] = array(
                              'taxonomy' => 'event_location',
                              'field' => 'slug',
                              'terms' => $location
                        );
                  }
                  if (! empty($_GET['event_topic'])) {
                        $topic = sanitize_text_field($_GET['event_topic']);
                        
                        $tax_query[] = array(
                              'taxonomy' => 'event_topic',
                              'field' => 'slug',
                              'terms' => $topic
                        );
                  }
            ?>
            <div class="latest-events">
                  <?php
                        $options = array(
                              'post_type' => 'latest_event',
                              'post_status' => 'publish',
                              'posts_per_page' => 5,
                              's' => $name,
                        );
                        if (! empty($tax_query)) {
                              $options['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
                        }
                        
                        $query = new WP_Query($options);
                        if($query->have_posts()) :
                  ?>
                  <div class="event-info">
                        <?php
                              while($query->have_posts()) :
                                    $query->the_post();
                        ?>
                        <div class="event-info-card">
                              <h2 class="event-title"><?php the_field('event_name'); ?></h2>
                              <p class="event-organizer">Event by: <?php the_field('event_organizer_name'); ?></p>
                              <p class="event-date">Event date: <?php the_field('event_date'); ?></p>
                              <?php
                                    $event_image = get_field('event_image'); 
                                    if ($event_image) :
                                    $url = $event_image['url'];
                                    $alt = $event_image['alt'];
                                    $width = $event_image['width'];
                                    $height = $event_image['height'];
                              ?> 
                              <img class="event-img" 
                                    src="<?php echo esc_url($url); ?>" 
                                    alt="<?php echo esc_attr($alt); ?>"
                                    width="<?php echo esc_attr($width); ?>"
                                    height="<?php echo esc_attr($height); ?>"
                              >
                              <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                              endwhile;
                        ?>
                  </div>
            <?php
                  wp_reset_postdata();
                  endif;
            ?>
            </div>
            <?php
            wp_die();
      }
}
```

Here is my JavaScript file

```
wp_register_script('custom-js', $uri . '/assets/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
                  wp_enqueue_script('custom-js');
                  wp_localize_script('custom-js', 'event_filter_url', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')),);
(function ($) {
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).submit('.form-submit', function(e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var name = $('#event_name').val();
                  var type = $('#event-type').val();
                  var location = $('#event-location').val();
                  var topic = $('#event-topic').val();
                  
                  var data = {
                        action: 'event_filters',
                        event_name: name,
                        event_type: type,
                        event_location: location,
                        event_topic: topic,
                  }
                  
                  $.ajax({
                        url: event_filter_url.ajax_url,
                        data: data,
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: function (response) {
                              $('.event-info').html(response);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                              console.warn(response);
                        }
                  });
            });
      });
})(jQuery);
```